# Openssl passin throws "Bad password read"

Tags: shell, openssl

Trying to encrypt a file & make executable using openssl. Found an interesting  [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/178325) that was suitable to my problem with one issue. which is "I had to pass the password used for encryption in openssl command" which is resulting error.

Create Write your script (script-base.sh)

```
#!/bin/sh 
echo "Hello World"
```

Encrypt your script (give a password): `foobar` is my password

```
openssl enc -e -aes-256-cbc -a -in script-base.sh > script-enc
```

Write de Wrapper (script-final.sh):

```
#!/bin/sh 
openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -a -in script-enc | sh -passin pass:foobar
```

Running "script-final.sh" I see following error in console

> enter aes-256-cbc decryption password: bad password read

Though the following code works but its deprecated

```
openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -a -in script-enc -k foobar | sh -
```

when used the following error is thrown

*** WARNING : deprecated key derivation used.
Using -iter or -pbkdf2 would be better.
bad decrypt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...  works but [] deprecated:  `openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -a -in script-enc -k foobar | sh -`

In that case you give `-k foobar` as an option to the `openssl enc -d` command, so it is used as the password to decrypt, which succeeds since you did in fact encrypt using `foobar` as the password (and the same cipher and default KDF). See below about deprecation.

> `openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -a -in script-enc | sh -passin pass:foobar` [gives]
> enter aes-256-cbc decryption password: bad password read

Here you didn't give `-passin pass:foobar` as an option to `openssl`, you gave it as an option to the *shell* that is the second component of the pipeline. Since you didn't give the password as an argument to *openssl* and it is needed, openssl prompted you to input it, but you didn't give valid input (perhaps entering control-D or similar) so it failed. If you did instead

```
openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -a -in script-enc -passin pass:foobar | sh
```

it would work *exactly* the same as the `-k` version, except for taking more space in your script.

It is indeed true that the key-derivation long used (and still default) by `openssl enc` is very poor and weak and has been widely criticized for decades; OpenSSL 1.1.1 (released 2018, after the date of the answer you link to) and up finally offers a better method with `-pbkdf2` and warns about using the old one. However, you should pay attention to this warning on the encrypt side rather than decrypt; once you've encrypted with the poor method, you must use it to decrypt (and suffer the warning). Also note, as I commented at that link, OpenSSL 1.1.x (and 3.0) are incompatible with earlier versions, so if any system(s) you or anyone (like your users if any) want this to work on are running older software it will fail.

Alternatively, consider using something that was properly designed in the first place, such as GPG which was recommended in the answer by Gilles on that same question (well over a year earlier). Although GPG, depending on the version, makes it less convenient to provide the password on the commandline because that usually allows it to be compromised -- but in your case you are already compromising it yourself, so GPG's attempt to give you security is wasted.